# MongoDB server warning

Tags: mongodb

I got those error when i try to start ***mongod*** --->

> C:\Users\DELL>mongod 2019-02-26T01:26:02.303+0500 I CONTROL  [main]
>   Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
>   --sslDisabledProtocols 'none' 2019-02-26T01:26:02.725+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6864 port=27017
>   dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-R0IAN8L
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.725+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS:
>   Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2 2019-02-26T01:26:02.726+0500 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.4
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.726+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:
>   f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839 2019-02-26T01:26:02.726+0500
>   I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.727+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.727+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
>   environment: 2019-02-26T01:26:02.727+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   distmod: 2008plus-ssl 2019-02-26T01:26:02.727+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64 2019-02-26T01:26:02.727+0500 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.728+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.731+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data
>   files in C:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so
>   setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.731+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=3536M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
>   2019-02-26T01:26:02.982+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   message [1551126362:981641][6864:140723279125216], txn-recover: Main
>   recovery loop: starting at 30/4224 to 31/256
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.178+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   message [1551126363:178773][6864:140723279125216], txn-recover:
>   Recovering log 30 through 31 2019-02-26T01:26:03.301+0500 I STORAGE 
>   [initandlisten] WiredTiger message
>   [1551126363:300813][6864:140723279125216], txn-recover: Recovering log
>   31 through 31 2019-02-26T01:26:03.399+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   WiredTiger message [1551126363:399614][6864:140723279125216],
>   txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.463+0500 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0) 2019-02-26T01:26:03.514+0500 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] 2019-02-26T01:26:03.514+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **
>
> > WARNING
>
> : Access control is not enabled for the database.
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.519+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>   Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.522+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.524+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **
>
> > WARNING
>
> : This server is bound to localhost. 2019-02-26T01:26:03.526+0500 I
>   CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to
>   connect to this server. 2019-02-26T01:26:03.534+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip 
>   to specify which IP 2019-02-26T01:26:03.536+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from,
>   or with --bind_ip_all to 2019-02-26T01:26:03.538+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior
>   is desired, start the 2019-02-26T01:26:03.540+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable
>   this warning. 2019-02-26T01:26:03.550+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.598+0500 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] BadValue:
>   Invalid value for version, found 4.2, expected '4.0' or '3.6'.
>   Contents of featureCompatibilityVersion document in
>   admin.system.version: { _id: "featureCompatibilityVersion", version:
>   "4.2" }. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-feature-compatibility.
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.599+0500 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT:
>
> > UPGRADE PROBLEM:
>
> Unable to parse the featureCompatibilityVersion document. The data
>   files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an
>   upgrade to 4.0. If you are upgrading to 4.0, see
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv.
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.607+0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
>   going to close listening sockets... 2019-02-26T01:26:03.609+0500 I
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
>   2019-02-26T01:26:03.868+0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>
> > shutdown:
>
> removing fs lock... 2019-02-26T01:26:03.869+0500 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]
>
> now exiting
>
> 2019-02-26T01:26:03.873+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>
> > shutting down with code
>
> :62

Comment: when i run "mongod" in cmd to start server then this error occur

Comment: The answer is in your error message *Unable to parse the featureCompatibilityVersion document. The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0.* https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-standalone/